# time bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb ----- the system cannot accept the time entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'm really hoping someone can answer a question for me. I've spent days configuring everything else I need for rubytutorial.org and I'm getting that familiar frustration that comes with Windows OS.

I am on section 3.6.3 Speeding up tests with Spork of Rubytutorial.org.

I just installed Guard and Spork.

Michael Hartl says, "Before running Spork, we can get a baseline for the testing overhead by timing our test suite as follows:"

```
$ time bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
......

6 examples, 0 failures

real    0m8.633s
user    0m7.240s
sys     0m1.068s
```

Below is what I receive.

```
time bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
The system cannot accept the time entered.
Enter the new time:
```

If anyone has an idea, I did try to search elsewhere... There's one resource by a guy http://someguyonrails.tumblr.com/post/29715188571/guard-spork-error-in-rails-tutorial-section-3-6, but his Gemfile is different than mine and the fix isn't the same. I think his is a work-around anyway.

Here is a quote from the page, "The first issue I encountered was when running the command "time bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb —drb," I got the following message in my command window "The system cannot accept the time entered. Enter the new time:" This remains unresolved, but I assume this implies that my Windows command prompt is not interpreting the “time” command the way the Tutorial expects. I’m not sure about this one so, feel free to shed some light on this."

I couldn't find anything else with what I searched.

Thanks..

Comment: "…and I'm getting that familiar frustration that comes with Windows OS" Praise the good Unix Lord. (/◔ ◡ ◔)/

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a Unix command that is not available natively on Windows. https://superuser.com/questions/228056/windows-equivalent-to-unix-time-command discussed a Powershell equivalent. I would instead recommend install Github for Windows, which will give you a bash shell, which is much more accommodating for Rails development. You should also strongly consider running Rails in Vagrant.